# How do I prove that $tr(A)=a_{11}+a_{22}=\lambda _1+\lambda _2$ for matrix $2\times 2$?

Tags: matrices

How do I prove that $tr(A)=a_{11}+a_{22}=\lambda _1+\lambda _2$ for matrix 2x2?

I think this is true for all $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: Recall that the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix. Now, is there a fast way to find the sum of the roots of a polynomial?

Comment: You can prove that $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$. Then you have $A=PTP^{-1}$ where $T=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & * & \dots & *\\
0&\ddots&\ddots &\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&*\\
0&\dots&0&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$. So that $Tr(A)=Tr(PTP^{-1})=Tr((PT)P^{-1})=Tr(P^{-1}(PT))=Tr((P^{-1}P)T)=Tr(T)=\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that characteristic polynomial for 2x2 matrices looks like  $P(x)=x^{2}-Tr(A)x+det(A)$ for some matrix $A$.
You also know that eigenvalues of a matrix are roots of characteristic polynomial.
Now just apply Vieta's formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true in general. It is not difficult to see that, if $A$ is square matrix of order $n$, then its characteristic polynomial is $$ p_A(\lambda)=a_0\lambda^n+ tr(A)\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{n-1}\lambda +det(A)$$. From algebra we know that the coefficient $a_1$ is also the sum of roots of the polynomial, then in your specific case the sum of the eigenvalues by definition.
Attention: maybe the roots does not belong to the field $\mathbb{K}$ you are considering, but belong to its splitting field $\mathbb{L}$, however, if all coefficient of the polynomial belong to $\mathbb{K}$ then the sum belong to $\mathbb{K}$.